# Reading Non Standard Namespace XML using E4X in AS3?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, e4x

I am trying to parse some XML in AS3 that I recieve thru a WebService call to C#. C# is serializing using a DataContract so the namespace is non standard.

**Here is what the xml looks like:**

```
<User xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UserDatabaseManipulation.POCO" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Email>
    <EmailString>
      bill@whitehouse.gov
    </EmailString>
  </Email>
  <Password>
    <PasswordPlainText>
      password
    </PasswordPlainText>
  </Password>
  <ReferralDetails>
    <ReferralEmail/>
    <ServiceCreatedAt>
      google
    </ServiceCreatedAt>    
  </ReferralDetails>
  <UserDetails>
    <Address>
      Penn Ave
    </Address>
    <City>
      Washington DC
    </City>
    <Country>
      USA
    </Country>
    <FirstName>
      Bill
    </FirstName>
    <LastName>
      Clinton
    </LastName>
    <State>
      AK
    </State>
    <Zip>
      11111
    </Zip>
  </UserDetails>
</User>
```

So as you can see from that I have a User which consists of Email, Password, Referral Details, and UserDetails.

**Here is where I parse it and the problem:**

```
private function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void
        {           
            var n:Namespace = new Namespace("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UserDatabaseManipulation.POCO");
            use namespace n;                    

//This WORKS! ResultXml is loaded with the correct looking XML.
            var resultXml:XML = new XML(event.result);  

//This doesnt work! I just end up with an empty XMLList.
            var email:Object = resultXml.Email;

...
```

Here's a screen shot in debug view (copy link and re-view to see it bigger):

[image]

**Without e4x I can get it to work like this but it is really clunky:**

```
var resultXml:XML = new XML(event.result);   // the whole block of XML

            var email:XML = resultXml.children()[0]; // the email object XML

            var emailText:XML = email.children()[0]; // the email text

            var emailActualXml:XML = emailText.children()[0]; // the email string in xml

            var emailString:String = emailActualXml.toString();
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**HERES THE SOLUTION**

```
var xmlNamespace:Namespace = new Namespace( // namespace in here );         

            var resultXml:XML = new XML(event.result);          

            var email:XMLList = resultXml.xmlNamespace::Email;

            var emailString:Object = email.xmlNamespace::EmailString.text().toString();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use the fully qualified name (including the namespace) when there are namespaces involved.

```
var n:Namespace = new Namespace("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UserDatabaseManipulation.POCO");
var resultXml:XML = new XML(event.result);  
var email:Object = resultXml.n::Email;
```

Or use the [default xml namespace](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_09.html) directive

```
default xml namespace = new Namespace("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UserDatabaseManipulation.POCO");

var resultXml:XML = new XML(event.result);  
var email:Object = resultXml.Email;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/f4m/1.0">
        <id>
    video_400
        </id>
        <streamType>
            recorded
        </streamType>
        <duration>
        87.823999999999998
        </duration>
        <bootstrapInfo profile="named" id="bootstrap9368">
        <metadata>
            ele mele
         </metadata>
        </bootstrapInfo>
    </manifest>



var xmlData:XML = new XML(loader.content as String) ;
var f4mNs : Namespace = xmlData.namespace();
trace(this + " onQueueComplete DURATION= " + xmlData.f4mNs::duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var email:XMLList = resultXml..Email;

//access the user email
var userEmail:String = String[email.EmailString];
```

Of course you could access EmailString directly with the dot syntax!

Comment: nope. no good :( I posted a screen shot showing this not working.